# How do i get a Text from a File and put it into an Array

Tags: lua

So Basically this is the text in the txt file:

```
hello, school, tommy, house, homemaking
```

I Want to put it into an Array So it looks like:

```lua
Array = {'hello', 'school', 'tommy', 'house', 'homemaking'}
```

and Not Like:

```lua
Array = {'hello, school, tommy, house, homemaking'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Lua 5.4 you can do a combination of `load()` `io.open()` and preparing it with three `gsub()` on the fly to convert the file content...

```
> array = load("return " .. io.open('text.txt', 'r'):read('*a'):gsub('^.', '{%1'):gsub('.$', '%1}'):gsub('%w+', '"%1"'))()
> print(#array)
5
> print(table.concat(array,'\n'))
hello
school
tommy
house
homemaking
```

The three gsub() do...

1. Replacing first sign with: `{ + first sign`
2. Replacing last sign with: `last sign + }`
3. Put all words into: `"word"`
   So at the end it is ready to convert...

```
{"hello", "school", "tommy", "house", "homemaking"
}
```

Comment: Thanks and also is there something that gets it without the " " as in numbers ex:
in the text file there is:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Should work if omitting the last ```gosub()```. Example: ```table.concat(load("return " .. ('1, 2, 3, 4, 5'):gsub('^.', '{%1'):gsub('.$', '%1}'))(), '\n')```

Comment: But be aware that this...```table.concat(load("return " .. ('math.pi, math.huge, math.atan(math.huge), math.atan(math.huge) * 2, math.maxinteger'):gsub('^.', '{%1'):gsub('.$', '%1}'))(), '\n')```...scratch at the edge of a security risk.